# Are there any references to Niralambopanishat and SukaRahasyopanishat prior to Adi Shankaracharya?

Tags: philosophy, upanishads, advaita, adi-shankaracharya

Among Vedantins; Advait is a widely followed philosophy. 
The famous quote of Shree Adi Shankaracharya goes:

> Brahma Satya, Jagat Mithya.

Now many Advaitins have mentioned that the verse was not concocted by Adi Shankara but he just quoted it from Niralambopanishat.

Similarly

> Jiva Brahmaieva

is said to be taken from ShukaRahasyopanishat.

However many sub-schools of Vedanta blame Adi Shankara and criticize His philosophy of being Crypto-Buddhist and so on. One thing I've often seen is them questioning the authenticity of these two Upanishads viz. Niralambopanishat and ShukaRahasyopanishat.

However as long as I know Niralambopanishat is also one of the 108 main upanishads (Ashtottar-Shat Upanishads)

So I'm interested in knowing if there are any references made to these Upanishads prior to Adi Shankaracharya.

Comment: No reference of muktikopanishat too. What to talk of rest of others